# Vuetify.js Grid | v-row keep exceeding mobile viewport width

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using v-container > v-layout > v-row of Vuetify.js, and contents of v-row keep exceeding width of the viewport. I tried the "overflow-x-hidden" class but that was not what I expected.

I will really appreciate it if you let me know to make v-row fill the viewport's width without exceeding it.

Thanks

```js
<template>
  <div id="app" class="back">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-row >
          <br><br><br><br>asdf
        </v-row>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not, please add some more information so we can continue to help you. If your problem is fixed now, please accept the correct answer or add your own answer so the community can benefit from your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `v-row` component is not designed to contain your content directly. Inside `v-row`, each section of your content should be wrapped in a `v-col` component, like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="back">
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-row >
          <v-col cols="12"> <!-- You can change the COLS attribute to make columns display side-by-side -->
            <br><br><br><br>asdf
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can read more about Vuetify's grid system [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids).

**EDIT:**

Also, you should not use `v-layout` and `v-row` in combination. `v-layout` is for Vuetify 1.x. `v-row` is for Vuetify 2.x. If you use `v-layout`, its child component should be `v-flex` instead of `v-col`.